# Taskbar width, height and position

Tags: delphi

I need to get the width and height of the taskbar. Also I need the position of the taskbar. How can I get this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, since this question is composed on how to get the task bar coordinates I've decided to post another version of how to achieve this by using [SHAppBarMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with [ABM_GETTASKBARPOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message parameter.

I've posted two versions; one with and one without given task bar handle. Note that if you are sending [ABM_GETTASKBARPOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message you should specify the hWnd member in the [APPBARDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure as it's mentioned in the [ABM_GETTASKBARPOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) description. So the first version is safe for this case. The second one works though but it's formally wrong.

```
uses ShellAPI;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Data: TAppBarData;
begin
  Data.hWnd := FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', nil);
  Data.cbSize := SizeOf(TAppBarData);

  if Data.hWnd <> 0 then
    if SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, Data) = 1 then
      ShowMessage(
                      'Left: ' + IntToStr(Data.rc.Left) + 'px ; ' +
                      'Top: ' + IntToStr(Data.rc.Top) + 'px ; ' +
                      'Width: ' + IntToStr(Data.rc.Right - Data.rc.Left) + 'px ; ' +
                      'Height: ' + IntToStr(Data.rc.Bottom - Data.rc.Top) + 'px'
                  );
end;
```

Note that this version (where the TAppBarData.hWnd member is not specified) works though but it's wrong according to the MSDN.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Data: TAppBarData;
begin
  Data.cbSize := SizeOf(TAppBarData);

  if SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, Data) = 1 then
    ShowMessage(
                    'Left: ' + IntToStr(Data.rc.Left) + 'px ; ' +
                    'Top: ' + IntToStr(Data.rc.Top) + 'px ; ' +
                    'Width: ' + IntToStr(Data.rc.Right - Data.rc.Left) + 'px ; ' +
                    'Height: ' + IntToStr(Data.rc.Bottom - Data.rc.Top) + 'px'
                );
end;
```

Comment: +1 for [SHAppBarMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762108(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Prund still uses findwindow or now it's not wrong ? ce iti mai place sa vrb aiurea

Answer (score 11):

Depending on what you need that information for, you might want to look into [Forms.TScreen.WorkAreaRect](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TScreen.WorkAreaRect), because the work-area identified that way subtracts not only *the* TaskBar, but also any other "bar" that might limit available Desktop space.

You can simply use `Screen.WorkAreaRect` from your code, because a `Screen: TScreen` variable is declared in the `Forms` unit and initialized by the VCL.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've got (made in the Win95 decade ;-) and still working):

- GetTaskBarBounds
- GetTaskBarSize
- GetTaskBarAlignment

Here is the code:

```
const
 W95_EXPLORERCLASSNAME = 'Shell_TrayWnd';

function GetTaskBarBounds : TRect;
begin
 GetWindowRect( FindWindow( W95_EXPLORERCLASSNAME, '' ), Result );
end;

function GetTaskBarSize : TPoint;
var
 TaskBarBounds : TRect;

begin
 TaskBarBounds:=GetTaskBarBounds;
 with( TaskBarBounds ) do
  Result:=Point( Right - abs( Left ), Bottom - abs( Top ) );
end;

function GetTaskBarAlignment : TAlign;
var
 TaskBarBounds : TRect;

begin
 Result:=alNone;

 if( FindWindow( W95_EXPLORERCLASSNAME, '' ) > 0 ) then
  begin
   TaskBarBounds:=GetTaskBarBounds;

   with( TaskBarBounds ) do
    // At Left or at top of screen ?
    if( Left <= 0 ) and ( Top <= 0 ) then
     begin
      if( Bottom >= 480 ) then
       Result:=alLeft
      else Result:=alTop;
     end
    else begin
          if( Left <= 0 ) then
           Result:=alBottom
          else Result:=alRight;
         end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you get the orientation

```
type
   TTaskBarPos = (_TOP, _BOTTOM, _LEFT, _RIGHT, _NONE);

function GetTaskBarPos: TTaskBarPos;
var
   hTaskbar: HWND;
   T: TRect;
   scrW, scrH: integer;
begin
   hTaskBar := FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', nil);
   if hTaskbar <> 0 then
   begin
     GetWindowRect(hTaskBar, T);
     ScrW := Screen.Width;
     ScrH := Screen.Height;
     if (T.Top > scrH div 2) and (T.Right >= scrW) then
       Result := _BOTTOM
     else if (T.Top < scrH div 2) and (T.Bottom <= scrW div 2) then
       Result := _TOP
     else if (T.Left < scrW div 2) and (T.Top <= 0) then
       Result := _LEFT
     else 
     if T.Left >= ScrW div 2 then
       Result := _RIGHT;
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   TaskBarPos: TTaskBarPos;
begin
   TaskBarPos := GetTaskBarPos;
   case TaskBarPos of
     _LEFT: ShowMessage('Left Position');
     _TOP: ShowMessage('Top Position');
     _RIGHT: ShowMessage('Right Position');
     _BOTTOM: ShowMessage('Bottom Position');
   end;
end;
```

Comment: the T variable holds the coord. of the taskbar so use that to get what you need ;)

Comment: To be honest this feel `hacky`, because it depends on `FindWindow`. This will fail if the user uses a non-standard Taskbar, will fail if there is more then one "bar", and I'm not sure what would happen on systems with multiple monitors.

Comment: @daemon_x bottom line is that the taskbar isn't for painting in. It's owned by the system.

Comment: @daemon_x let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/963/discussion-between-david-heffernan-and-daemon-x)

Comment: hacky or not i don't see a working solution from the MASTERS OF CODING david and prund 2 super heroes sent back in time to solve the problems of delphi programming.I find your comments boring i thought this site is about multiple users working on solution and then someone voting the bestsolution or am i wrong?

Comment: Something tells me this code doesn't properly account for multiple monitors.

Comment: @opc0de I didn't post an answer because I don't know anything about this. I do know that hunting 'Shell_TrayWnd' is to be avoided. `ABM_GETTASKBARPOS` looks good. Work area is good too.  And as Rob says you don't deal with multiple monitors.

Comment: @David Programming is not about doing things by the book programming is about beeing creative and btw ABM_GETTASKBAR position still uses findwindow with shell_traywnd as param look into msdn ;)

Comment: @opc0de Where on MSDN does it mention anything about `'Shell_TrayWnd'` in connection with `ABM_GETTASKBARPOS`? You just call `SHAppBarMessage` and the `RECT` is returned.  You don't need to pass in an `HWND`.  The docs are misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I got this code from http://www.delphitips.net/2007/08/26/taskbar-position I tried this and works fine. It works even the size of the taskbar changes.

The code is put below.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  hTaskbar: HWND;
  T: TRect;
  ScrW, ScrH: Integer;
begin
  ScrW := Screen.Width;
  ScrH := Screen.Height;
  hTaskBar := FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', nil);
  GetWindowRect(hTaskBar, T);
  if (T.Top > ScrH div 2) and (T.Right >= ScrW) then
    ShowMessage('Bottom of the screen')
  else if (T.Top < ScrH div 2) and (T.Bottom <= ScrW div 2) then
    ShowMessage('Top of the screen')
  else if (T.left < ScrW div 2) and (T.Top <= 0) then
    ShowMessage('Left side of the screen')
  else
    ShowMessage('Right side of the screen');
end;
```